# How to properly close connection to SQLite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem that I suddenly get a lot of SQLite3 Operational errors - my database is locked. I think it is because I open the database for quite many times in my program. So, how do I ensure this isn't happening?

```
def getID(databasepath):
    con = lite.connect(databasepath)
    with con:
        cur = con.execute("SELECT userid, name from Table")
        con.commit()
        rows = [[x[0], x[1]] for x in cur]
    con.close()
    return rows

def findIDsomewhereElse(databasepath):
    con = lite.connect(databasepath)
    with con:
        cur = con.execute("SELECT userid FROM table2")
        con.commit()
        all_rows = cur.fetchall()
        all_rows = sorted(all_rows, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
    con.close()
    return all_rows
```

Main:

```
id = getId('firstpath')
userid = id[0]
con = lite.connect('secondpath')
    with con:
            cur = con.execute("SELECT max(time) FROM enteringSing WHERE userid = {userid}".format(userid = userid))
            con.commit()
con.close()
newfind = findIDsomewhereElse('secondpath')
con = lite.connect('secondpath')
with con:
    con.executemany("INSERT INTO table4(columns) VALUES(?)", allrows)
     con.commit()
con.close()
```

So I connect to that database fairly often, is that the problem? I realize i probably should probably put the con lite connect outside the methods? But then again, I use a total of two databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it seems it helped to start running the python files through terminal and python file.py rather han just ctrl+B in sublimetext2.